# How do I examine a cross-compiled struct that has been dumped to file?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, embedded, cross-compiling

I have a program running on an ARM-based embedded device. A certain `struct`, globally accessible, is being dumped every so often to disk and represents about 160Kb of data.

I need to examine the contents of this structure. So far I have used a Python script together with the `struct` library to parse the contents of that dump, but this approach doesn't scale very well.

I thought it was possible to use the cross-compiling GDB program to do this. I want to copy the contents of that file back into memory, at the address of the structure. So this is what I tried:

```
$ arm-eabi-gdb
....
(gdb) target sim
Connected to the simulator.
(gdb) file MS.elf
Reading symbols from MS.elf...done.
(gdb) p &my_struct
$1 = (MyStruct *) 0x6801149c
(gdb) restore ~/Dumps/MS_20121128_164606 binary 0x6801149c
You can't do that without a process to debug.
```

**Is this the correct approach? If yes, what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Two things come to mind: (1) attach gdb to an arbitrary process, examine the structure in the context of that process; (2) use gdb's `ptype` command to get a description of the structure, and generate e.g. a Python parsing script from that description.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a small program that reads in the struct and then in the
debug mode print it.

The program needs to be compiled on system with the same 
architecture characteristics as ARM.  I.e. same sizeof 
char, int, short, long, float, double and pointer.
Also, the byte ordering needs to be the same as on ARM.

If you are looking at the struct often, then it would be 
worth pretty printing out the contents of the struct 
instead of constantly using gdb to see the contents.

Since the structure is quite large, I would also go the
extra step of using an API that puts the structure
in a folder/document type tree in a browser so that
you can zoom in or browse different parts of the struct.
If anyone interested in this, let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Foo {       
    /* contents of the struct go here */
};        

int
main()
{     
    struct Foo tmp;
    int fd, r, n = sizeof(tmp);

    fd = open("struct_dump", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("could not open struct_dump.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    r = read(fd, &tmp, n);
    if (r != n) {
        printf("mismatched struct sizes.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    /*
     * Stop here in gdb and do 'p tmp'
     */

    close(fd);
    exit(0);
 }
```